# Commutator of number operator

Tags: operators

a=$\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat X +i\hat P_x)$
a$\dagger=\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}(\hat X -i\hat P_x)$
number operator N=a$^\dagger$a is hermitian
hence, a$^\dagger$a=aa$^\dagger$
[a,a$^\dagger$]=0
But,
[a,a$^\dagger$]=$\frac {1}{2}[\hat X+ i \hat P_x,\hat X- i \hat P_x]$
                                 =$\frac {1}{2}[\hat X+ i \hat P_x,\hat X]+[\hat X+ i \hat P_x,- i \hat P_x]$
              =$\frac {1}{2}[i \hat P_x,\hat X]+[\hat X,- i \hat P_x]$
=$\frac {1}{2}*-2i[\hat X, \hat P_x]$
=-i*i
=1

Answer (score 0):

What? Notice that
$$(X Y)^\dagger = Y^\dagger X^\dagger \neq X^\dagger Y^\dagger.$$
 In particular, if $X = a^\dagger$ and $Y = a$, we get $$(a^\dagger a)^\dagger = a^\dagger a \neq a a^\dagger.$$